# 404 not found after activating Joomla 2.5 URL rewriting at localhost

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

I have a copy of my website at localhost at:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs
```

This is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've copied htaccess.txt to .htaccess. When I activate friendly URL and URL rewriting, I get 404 errors.

I've uncommented this lines in .htaccess, but still does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I also tried to change rewritebase to

```
RewriteBase /mysite
```

with no luck.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
I had a conflict with different entries in /etc/apache2/sites-available.
When I create a new site at localhost, I copy `default` to `mysite`, and modify the `mysite` file to point to it's DocumentRoot.
I don't know exactly why, but if I disable default site:

```
sudo a2dissite default
```

it works.

Maybe this does'nt solve the question, but I prefer to issue another question more specific to this problem, because I've tested and it's related to different sites enabled and one or more with RewriteEngine enabled.

Answer (score 1):

No sure if this is the issue you are experiencing, but I have experienced that rewriting does not work well on "localhost". Try and change your hosts file to say

```
127.0.0.1     mysite.local
```

And then access it on that url.

Not sure if that will work but it is worth a try.

Comment: Hi Søren. It's still not working. I have another site at localhost (pure PHP) and URL rewriting is working fine. Thanks anyway